# What is the "s" of third person verbs called in English grammar terminology?

Tags: grammar, terminology

What is the "s" of *third person singular* verbs called in English grammar terminology?

For example: do**es**, love**s**, work**s**, etc.

Comment: It's not the name of the "s" itself, but in case you were unaware, the process of changing the ending or form of verbs based on person (as well as other factors) is called [conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation).

Answer (score 10):

It's called the *third person singular -s*.

Source: Bas Aarts et al., *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* Second edition, page 243

Answer (score 9):

It is an **ending** or a **suffix**.  Specifically it is the *third-person singular ending* in the *present* tense.  (Some would add *indicative*; others consider that term confusing in the context of present-day English.)

You shouldn't call it simply the "third-person" ending.  It is third-person *singular*.